# netbeans: Attach image in Jlabel using Jbutton

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jlabel

How to create a personal detail which I need to attach to a personal image? When clicking the button, it can select the picture, but I still cannot figure it out how to set this coding, any one can help solve this?

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();

personal_image.
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted that you're using NetBeans IDE, NetBeans already provides the facility to write the actionPerformed for a JButton in case of an ActionEvent.

I suggest you write the following code in your JButton's actionPerformed with ActionEvent evt as mentioned below :-

```
private void DesiredButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

 // Add your mentioned code here before coding this.
 try{
 Image image = ImageIO.read(f);
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
 // JLabel toBeSet = new JLabel(); 
 // considering that you have a JLabel having name as what I've used here
 toBeSet.setIcon(icon);
 }
 catch(IOException ioe){
 System.out.println("Exception occured while setting Image on the Label!");
 }

}
```

Comment: 1) That code as written will have no visible affect since the newly created label is never added to anything.  Further, special considerations are required for adding components to a GUI after it has been made visible.  2) Overall, the code would suggest `personal_image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(f));` 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: @AndrewThompson-Yes SIR, I am removing that JLabel from there. It was just meant to be get reference,which I will make it presume that it already exists.
SIR, also already mentioned that he's using NetBeans IDE. SO, he might have used the well-defined functionality of NetBeans automatic Swing handling. And, SIR, moreover OP's question was to how to add image to label using JButton----I mentioned that how he will handle this logic.

Comment: No, where have I done that? Please point me, your `f` I have renamed as a `file`. @JiunJye

Comment: Image image = ImageIO.read(file); the file show unreportedexception IOexception; must be caough or declare must be thrown

Comment: @shekharsuman  1) If you are referring to my 2nd comment (please be specific about such things) note that I was referring to the OP's code.  Look at it again. If `personal_image` is a `JLabel` it can be completed in a single line of code. 2) Tip: Add `@AndrewThompson` (or whoever, the `@` is important) & *do it consistently* to notify the person of a new comment. 3) My name is Andrew, not SIR and there is no need to SHOUT either way.

Comment: Well, you use this :- ` 
Image image = ImageIO.read(f);` . The difference is that I have mistakenly used file instance as file! @JiunJye

Comment: @AndrewThompson - 1) I don't know how can you decide whether that personal_image is a JLable. I don't have any reason to think so. 
2) I am already using that convention. 3)It's my way of referring seniors over here by showing respect as I am almost 25 years junior to you. And, really, am I shouting? I don't think so. I requested you to just remove this downvote. BY the way,finally it is your choice.

Comment: *"Please suggest any mistakes which I should edit."*  Let's start with - the indentation of that code is still non-existent.  The method name does not fit the usual nomenclature.  Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. Then there is your continuing to write *"SIR"*.  But to be blunt, the answer is premature and crap upon crap.  I could not be bothered with it further..

Comment: @AndrewThompson-SIR, I am feeling SORRY for myself as till today what respect I carried for you! Next, I am aware of common Java nomenclature. I copy-pasted one of the JButton's actionPerformed() from my NetBeans auto-generated Swing. Then next, Mr. Andrew- and i don't think my answer is premature OR crap. It clearly delivers the way how OP should get the answer. I am not sitting here to write a Swing tutorial for OP to how to add Buttons,Labels,FileChooser,etc!

Comment: sry... 
Image image = ImageIO.read(f); the f is showing unreported exception IOexception; must be caugh or declare must be thrown

Comment: Yes, it will throw an IOException, Use a `try{...} catch(IOException ioe){...}` block to handle the same @JiunJye . Search Google for a try-catch block in Java

Comment: @AndrewThompson- Mr. Andrew, Please see that OP's problem was resolved with that *"premature and crap upin crap code"* with such an insane method-indentation. I request you to kindly take away that downvote. But,it' still your say.